# Attached options backbone 1.1.2 view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hi I've read that to use options attached in a view in newest version of Backbone,people must add this code:

```
app.View = Backbone.View.extend({

  constructor: function (options) {
    this.configure(options || {});
    // ...
    Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  configure: function (options) {
    if (this.options) {
      options = _.extend({}, _.result(this, 'options'), options);
    }
    this.options = options;
  }

});
```

but I don't know where insert it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the snippet you posted creates a base view which you are then meant to use when extending instead of the backbone.js view.

For a bit more detail, in the past when you passed in options to a view backbone.js would automatically attach them to the view under `this.options`, as of [version 1.1.0](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) backbone no longer does this automatically for you. However you can still do this yourself manually on a per view basis, for example

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

     initialize: function (options) {
       this.options = options;
     }

})
```

Or alternativelly you can create your own base view that does that and then when you create your view's extend that view instead (which is what the snippet you posted does).

For example

```
var myView = app.View.extend({
  //...
});
```

And here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jayopuxe/1/)